# Xprof output to file

Tags: java, profiling

I'm running java with the -Xprof option. I'm wondering if there's a way to output the profiler information to a file rather than stdout.

Answer (score 4):

If running from a command line you can try `>`, ie:

```
java -Xprof YourClass > output.txt
```

Not sure what kind of profiling you do and what is the nature of your application, but you may consider a bit friendlier profiler, for example [Eclipse TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/) or [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html).